# Button or Shortcut in for Windows Explorer to quickly hide/show the navigation pane

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer

For Windows 7/8/2008/2012 and above...

How can i create a button or shortcut in for Windows Explorer to quickly hide or show the navigation pane...

With the Preview Pane we can use the keyboard shortcut Alt+P (no button in toobar available)...
but no shortcut or button for the Navigation Pane... only via the File menu...

So the ideal would be a button in the toolbar to show/hide this pane...

Comment: _"Alt+P (no button in toobar available)"_ There is a button at the right end of the toolbar (Windows 7) to hide or show the preview pane.

Comment: the example I gave with Alt+P was just to illustrate what functionality I want to have with the "Navigation Pane"...

Answer (score 1):

## Add a Navigation pane button to all folder types

The following procedure will add a quick way to toggle the navigation pane, right next to the **Organize** button.

### Preliminary steps

1. Log on with an administrator account.
2. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, type or paste `regedit.exe` in the text box, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. Navigate to the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\Windows.navpane` registry key.
4. Right-click the registry key, and select **Permissions** from the context menu.
5. Click the **Advanced** button, and click the **Owner** tab. Enable the **Replace owner on subcontainers and object** option, select the **Administrators** group from the list, and click **OK**.
6. Select the **Administrators** group from the **Security** list, and enable the **Allow** check box for the **Full Control** option. Apply the changes, then click **OK**.
7. Right-click an empty area in the right pane, and choose **New > String Value** from the menu. Name the new value as `Position`, and set it to `After`.
8. Create a new string value called `PositionCompare`, and set it to `{7ddc1264-7e4d-4f74-bbc0-d191987c8d0f}`.
9. Repeat steps 3-6 for the following registry keys:

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes\{5c4f28b5-f869-4e84-8e60-f11db97c5cc7}
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes\{5fa96407-7e77-483c-ac93-691d05850de8}
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes\{7d49d726-3c21-4f05-99aa-fdc2c9474656}
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes\{94d6ddcc-4a68-4175-a374-bd584a510b78}
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes\{b3690e58-e961-423b-b687-386ebfd83239}
   ```

### Batch automation

There are many folder types, and making the required changes by hand would be annyoing. Save the following code as `AddNavPaneButton.cmd` (or whatever, as long it has the .cmd extension), and run it as administrator.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
pushd "%~dp0"

REM Contacts.Library, Contacts.LibraryFolder
REM Contacts.SearchResults, Documents
REM Documents.Library, Documents.LibraryFolder
REM Documents.SearchResults, Generic
REM Generic.Library, Generic.LibraryFolder
REM Generic.SearchResults, Music
REM Music.Library, Music.LibraryFolder
REM Music.SearchResults, OpenSearch
REM OtherUsers, OtherUsers.SearchResults
REM Pictures, Pictures.Library
REM Pictures.LibraryFolder, Pictures.SearchResults
REM PublishedItems, PublishedItems.SearchResults
REM Searches, UserFiles
REM UserFiles.SearchResults, UsersLibraries
REM UsersLibraries.SearchResults, Videos
REM Videos.Library, Videos.LibraryFolder
REM Videos.SearchResults

set key=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes
set subkeys=^
 {524ddb2b-2a4f-43b8-b8fe-e91ef9d8ba69},{654a1b99-8a4b-4e7b-a4e1-46378ad77a61},^
 {20338b7b-531c-4aad-8011-f5b3db2123ec},{7d49d726-3c21-4f05-99aa-fdc2c9474656},^
 {fbb3477e-c9e4-4b3b-a2ba-d3f5d3cd46f9},{3f98a740-839c-4af7-8c36-5badfb33d5fd},^
 {36011842-dccc-40fe-aa3d-6177ea401788},{5c4f28b5-f869-4e84-8e60-f11db97c5cc7},^
 {5f4eab9a-6833-4f61-899d-31cf46979d49},{da3f6866-35fe-4229-821a-26553a67fc18},^
 {7fde1a1e-8b31-49a5-93b8-6be14cfa4943},{94d6ddcc-4a68-4175-a374-bd584a510b78},^
 {3f2a72a7-99fa-4ddb-a5a8-c604edf61d6b},{978e0ed7-92d6-4cec-9b59-3135b9c49ccf},^
 {71689ac1-cc88-45d0-8a22-2943c3e7dfb3},{8faf9629-1980-46ff-8023-9dceab9c3ee3},^
 {B337FD00-9DD5-4635-A6D4-DA33FD102B7A},{3D1D4EA2-1D8C-418a-BFF8-F18370157B55},^
 {b3690e58-e961-423b-b687-386ebfd83239},{0b2baaeb-0042-4dca-aa4d-3ee8648d03e5},^
 {c1f8339f-f312-4c97-b1c6-ecdf5910c5c0},{4dcafe13-e6a7-4c28-be02-ca8c2126280d},^
 {7F2F5B96-FF74-41da-AFD8-1C78A5F3AEA2},{921C636D-9FC8-40d7-899E-0845DCD03010},^
 {0b0ba2e3-405f-415e-a6ee-cad625207853},{CD0FC69B-71E2-46e5-9690-5BCD9F57AAB3},^
 {e053a11a-dced-4515-8c4e-d51ba917517b},{C4D98F09-6124-4fe0-9942-826416082DA9},^
 {59BD6DD1-5CEC-4d7e-9AD2-ECC64154418D},{5fa96407-7e77-483c-ac93-691d05850de8},^
 {631958a6-ad0f-4035-a745-28ac066dc6ed},{292108be-88ab-4f33-9a26-7748e62e37ad},^
 {ea25fbd7-3bf7-409e-b97f-3352240903f4}

for %%A in (%subkeys%) do (
set value1=
set value2=
for /f "tokens=3" %%B in ('"reg query "%key%\%%A" /ve /f "TasksItemsSelected" /k /s 2>&1 | findstr /c:"REG_SZ" "') do set value1=%%B
for /f "tokens=3" %%C in ('"reg query "%key%\%%A" /ve /f "TasksNoItemsSelected" /k /s 2>&1 | findstr /c:"REG_SZ" "') do set value2=%%C

if defined value2 (
echo !value1!|findstr /c:"Windows.navpane" >nul
if !errorlevel! == 1 (set value1=Windows.navpane;!value1!)
echo !value2!|findstr /c:"Windows.navpane" >nul
if !errorlevel! == 1 (set value2=Windows.navpane;!value2!)
) else (
set value1=Windows.navpane
set value2=Windows.navpane
)

reg add "%key%\%%A\TasksItemsSelected" /ve /t REG_SZ /d !value1! /f >nul
reg add "%key%\%%A\TasksNoItemsSelected" /ve /t REG_SZ /d !value2! /f >nul
)

popd
pause & exit /b
```

## References

- [FOLDERTYPEID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bb762581%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
- [Toggle Navigation Pane](http://sourceforge.net/p/classicshell/discussion/1049756/thread/ca79258f)
- [How to Customize Command Bar in Windows 7 Explorer? Add Cut, Copy, Paste and Other Useful Buttons](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-customize-windows-explorer-command-bar-aka-folder-band-or-toolbar-in-windows-vista-and-7-add-cut-copy-paste-delete-rename-undo-and-many-other-useful-buttons/)

Answer (score 0):

After lots of web diggin' I've found just what I was talking about...

[image]

There is an tweak to add any button to the Explorer Command Bar of Windows 7

Open
    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes

Take ownership of this key and subkeys and grant permissions so you can create keys
and change values...

As childs of this key you will find each key name as a GUID
each GUID represents a windows special folder...

Find {5c4f28b5-f869-4e84-8e60-f11db97c5cc7} wich is for "Generic" folders
as you can check by looking the value of the subkey "CanonicalName"

Under this key (the GUID key) create two subkeys: 
    TasksItemsSelected
    TasksNoItemsSelected

edit the "(Default)" value of this 2 created keys and add the following commands 
separated by a semicolon: 
    Windows.navpane; Windows.properties

As the keys names state
    the first one (TasksItemsSelected) is for some items selected
    the second one (TasksNoItemsSelected) is for no items selected

You can now make a test to check the functionality...
just open a drive or folder in explorer and you'll see the 
"Navigation pane" and "Properties" buttons in the command bar

If you are interested in obtaining other explorer funcionalities,
all possible toolbar commands are listed in
    HKLM\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore

Enjoy